# Accessing a Slide with index in a presentation using Python.pptx

Tags: python-pptx

I am trying to create thousands of powerpoint presentations using Powerpoint VBA. Few days back I have learned python is the better tool to solve my issues which VBA cannot solve. So I am learning python.pptx to create those presentation and I am doing fine. But I need to access some slides in powerpoint presentations and edit them according to my needs. If I can get access to a slide using index or in any other way I can easy handle the rest of my problems.
I want to insert a slide in between slides. I have browsed many web pages but found nothing on this.
Can some one help me with this?

```
 from pptx import Presentation
 prs = Presentation('my-presentation')
 Slide_1 = prs.slides[1]
 # i want to insert a slide in betweeen these two slides (2nd and 3rd 
   slides) #

 Slide_2 = prs.slides[2]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The problem you're asking about is "How to insert a slide at specific index" and doesn't have to do with accessing a slide per se. If you search on "python-pptx insert slide at index" you'll find some helpful results.

Comment: Thank you. I think I found that .